# Stock price change, quantitatively

Tags: finance, economics

People say that when you sell a stock its price goes down, and when you buy it the price goes up.
This is clear, qualitatively, but I never really understood how much the price changes.
Could you clarify in simple mathematical terms with a numerical example?

[Sept 13, 2022 update] Finlay Morrison kindly provided some insight but I still don't grasp the mechanism. Thanks

[Sept 26, 2022 Update] I found the answer at the link below. it is a series of three Youtube videos.Thank you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gDMNIU4LOk&list=PLFdGt__jX7eNh5sQUkUXG8yLeNlRna1fI&index=1&ab_channel=CriticalTrading

Comment: A market will have several buy and sell orders set at different prices. The price reported will be determined by these orders, for simplicity lets just say its the arithmetic mean of the lowest sell order and the highest buy order. When you buy a stock you will buy from that lowest sell order, and so the new lowest sell order is now higher, and therefore the average of the sell order and buy order is now higher also. The amount which it changes varies heavily upon the volume of sell orders, if there are many sell orders all at the lowest sell order price you would not move the price at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I am trying to understand the actual mechanism, not the simplified version of it. Also I don't understand the second part, in quote below. "When you buy a stock you will buy from that lowest sell order, and so the new lowest sell order is now higher, and therefore the average of the sell order and buy order is now higher also. The amount which it changes varies heavily upon the volume of sell orders, if there are many sell orders all at the lowest sell order price you would not move the price at all"

Comment: Please don't ask us to watch ( a ***series*** of ?) youtube videos. Extract some mathematical content and ask a specific question.